# How to detect when map has finished resizing

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I need to update some UI elements locations that are dependent on map coordinates, in realtime. At some point my UI layout changes and the map is resized, then it animates to adjust to the new size. I can't find a way to detect when the view is finished resizing.

I can easily detect camera move events but they don't seem to be firing on resize.

Comment: There is method _OnMapLoadedCallback_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the documentation :

[image]
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback

any changes to maps should be done inside this callback, alternatively have a look at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.

To potentially check for resizing of the map, have a look at this from the OnMapReadyCallback:
[image]

Meaning that you might have to implement a  `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` for the specific map and based off of that you could potentially implement changes while resizing.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will be what I'm looking for. Any idea if there is an event that fires WHILE resizing and animating so I can do real time updates?

Comment: Consider giving my answer an upvote if it helped :) as for resizing , i'm not too sure, i cant find anything in the documentation looking at it briefly,might not be possible directly

Comment: Actually, it might be possible

Comment: @jur I updated my answer to include a possible solution for resizing, hope it helps

Comment: no problem, as long as it helped ;) happy coding @jur

Answer (score 0):

```
open class MapFragment() : BaseFragment(), OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {
}
```

Use OnMapReadyCallback,to know if map is ready or loaded initially

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {}
```

And use GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback,to know if map is loaded after changes.

```
 override fun onMapLoaded() {}
```